# Website crashing when I reload too many times

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am creating a discord bot dashboard and whenever I spam reload my website, this error comes up `TypeError: serverInfo.forEach is not a function` . This only comes when I reload really quickly like 5 times and not when it loads for the first time. It also happens when I go from one page to another quickly. Is there a fix for this? I use node.js, express and ejs. This is localhost BTW

Here is the code :

```
router.get('/:serverid', loginChecker, async(req, res) => {

    const server_id = req.params.serverid;
    const accessToken = req.cookies.Access_Token;

    const fetchDiscordUserInfo = await fetch('http://discordapp.com/api/users/@me', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        }
    });

    const userInfo = await fetchDiscordUserInfo.json();
    
    const userID = userInfo.id;
    const userUsername = userInfo.username;
    const userAvatar = userInfo.avatar;


    const fetchDiscordServerInfo = await fetch('http://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds', {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        }
    });

    const serverInfo = await fetchDiscordServerInfo.json();
    const accessableServers = [];

    //Error is over here
    await serverInfo.forEach(permission => {

        var userPermissions = new Permissions(permission.permissions).any('ADMINISTRATOR');

        if(userPermissions == true){
            accessableServers.push(permission);
        }

    });
    
    const filteredServerInfo = await accessableServers.map( (server) => {

        var filteredServer = {'id' : server.id,'icon' : server.icon, 'selected_icon' : false}
        return filteredServer;

    })

    const ids = await filteredServerInfo.map((server) => {
        var serverIds = (server.id);
        return serverIds;
    })

    const i = ids.indexOf(server_id);

    filteredServerInfo[i].selected_icon = true;

    await res.render('moderation', {'filteredServerInfo' : filteredServerInfo,'userID' : userID, 'userUsername' : userUsername , 'userAvatar' : userAvatar});

})
```

EDIT :

I added an error handler that redirects them back to the link that they were in and its fixed :

```
const catchAsyncErrors = (fn) => (req, res, next) => {

  const routePromise = fn(req, res, next);

  if (routePromise.catch) {
    routePromise.catch((err) => next(res.redirect('/dashboard')));
  }
};

exports.catchAsync = catchAsyncErrors;
```

Comment: Why use `await` on `serverInfo.forEach`? `forEach` doesn't obey promises, even if it did there's no awaits in the loop.

Comment: well there was no await there but it still showed a problem. So I thought it might have been because the serverInfo array hadn't loaded in yet.

Comment: Add some error handling around `fetch('http://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds'`

Comment: i was just trying a possibility of someone crashing my website

Comment: @KevinB  How is this error handler?
`
const catchAsyncErrors = (fn) => (req, res, next) => {

  const routePromise = fn(req, res, next);

  if (routePromise.catch) {
    routePromise.catch((err) => next(err));
  }
};

exports.catchAsync = catchAsyncErrors;`

Comment: fetch doesn't throw an error if the request completed, even if the server returned a non-200 response. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch you should check the response to make sure it's actually successful before moving on with the assumption that it's successful.

Comment: what is the result of `serverInfo` in your console? `console.log('serverInfo', serverInfo)`

Answer (score 0):

I created an error handler like @Kevin B said and it works now. However, it still shows the error.

Here is the error handler :

```
const catchAsyncErrors = (fn) => (req, res, next) => {

  const routePromise = fn(req, res, next);

  if (routePromise.catch) {
    routePromise.catch((err) => next(err));
  }
};

exports.catchAsync = catchAsyncErrors;
```

Comment: It's best to edit your question with new info instead of answering yourself with another question.

Comment: this isn't the answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that when you reload quickly the data hasn't been fetched so thanks to hoisting, `serverInfo` initial value would be `undefined`.

So therefore what I suggest is to have an if statement before the loop that checks if the value is an array that isn't empty else the route will respond with some empty data.

```js
//... code here
    const serverInfo = await fetchDiscordServerInfo.json();
    const accessableServers = [];
    
    if (!Array.isArray(serverInfo)) {
      return await res.render('moderation', {filteredServerInfo: [],userID: null, userUsername: null , userAvatar: null});
    }

    //Error is over here
    await serverInfo.forEach(permission => {
        const userPermissions = new Permissions(permission.permissions).any('ADMINISTRATOR');

        if (userPermissions == true){
            accessableServers.push(permission);
        }

    });
//... code here
```